# The old Chestnut "printf" and combinations in java

Tags: java

I'm writing a proggy that will print a combination of doubles and text.

MY CODE:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double seatCount = 10.50;
        double count = 11.58654;
        double stFare = 87.78965;
        

        System.out.printf(count / stFare + " * Standard  @ $ " + stFare + " = $" + count);
    }
}
```

WHICH PRINTS:

0.13198070615385754 * Standard  @ $ 87.78965 = $11.58654

how can I incorporate %X.Xf to round the first figure to a number with no decimal places and the last two figures to 2 x deciaml places i.e.,

1 * Standard  @ $87.78 = $87.78

PS: The calculaions are wrong, they are just samples for the sake of putting numbers in!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`System.out.printf("%.0f * Standard  @ $ %.2f = $ %.2f", count / stFare, stFare, count);`

Because that's the syntax for the placeholders for `printf`: `%[flags][width][.precision]conversion-character` and `f` is the conversion-character for floating point numbers like you have with `double`.